# Copy first n lines of each file in a directory

Tags: haskell, file-system

In an attempt to learn Haskell, I've built this - it accepts a number *n*, a source directory, and a sink directory  (ending with `/`) copies *n* lines from each file in the source directory to the sink directory.  It is not recursive. Thoughts?

```
module Main where
import System.Directory
import Control.Monad
import System.IO
import System.IO.Error
import Data.List
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Exception.Base
import System.Environment
import Data.List

--requires / or \ at end.
listFilesInDir :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
listFilesInDir dir= (getDirectoryContents dir) >>= filterM (\x ->doesFileExist $ dir ++ x)

readAndWrite:: Handle -> Handle -> IO ()
readAndWrite inHandle outHandle = do
    myLn<-tryIOError(hGetLine inHandle)
    case myLn of
         Left e -> if isEOFError e
                   then return ()
                   else ioError e
         Right myLn -> do hPutStrLn outHandle myLn
                          return ()


writeFirstNLines :: Int-> FilePath->FilePath -> IO ()
writeFirstNLines n source sink =do
    inHandle <- openFile source ReadMode
    outHandle <- openFile sink WriteMode
    replicateM_ n (readAndWrite inHandle outHandle)


main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let n = read $ args!!0
    let source = args!!1
    let sink   = args!!2
    let fileList=listFilesInDir  source
    fileSources <-fmap (map (source ++)) $ fileList
    fileSinks <-fmap (map (sink ++)) $ fileList
    --putStrLn "Sources"
    --mapM_ putStrLn fileSources
    --putStrLn "Sinks"
    --mapM_ putStrLn fileSinks
    q<-zipWithM (writeFirstNLines n) fileSources fileSinks
    return()
```

Comment: some extra whitespace here and there around operators would do good to readability!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**requires / or \ at end.**

Your code requires that the user supplied source and destination
directories end in a path name separator. A better approach is
to simply add it. See the comments below on the `(</>)` operator.

**partial functions**

When processing the command line arguments you 
are using functions which could throw errors, e.g. `read`, `head`, `!!`.
When they fail you'll get a generic error message like `Prelude.read: no parse` or `Prelude.!!: index too large`.

Hackage has libraries you can use to parse and validate command line arguments
like [**cmdargs**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cmdargs) or any of the [**optparse-**](https://hackage.haskell.org/packages/search?terms=optparse) packages. However, it's not too difficult to roll your own like this:

```
 import Data.Char

 parseArgs (nstr : source : dest : _) =
   if all isDigit nstr
     then ( read nstr, source, dest )
     else error "first argument is not a number"
 parseArgs _ = error "not enough arguments"

main = do
  args <- getArgs
  let (n, source, dest) = parseArgs args
  ...
```

`parseArgs` checks that there are at least three command line arguments and
also that the first one consists entirely of digits.

**(++)**

Currently the `FilePath` type is a `String`, so using `(++)` to join
together path name segments is fine. However, in [System.FilePath](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/filepath-1.4.0.0/docs/System-FilePath-Posix.html)
Haskell defines the operator `(</>)` which is meant to be a cross-platform
way to do this - i.e. on Windows it will use `\\` and on Posix systems it
will use a `/`. Moreover using `(</>)` signals to the reader that you are
working with a path name string.

The module `System.FilePath` also has utility functions for dealing with
path names such as extracting the base / directory name from a path, extracting and replacing the suffix, etc. which are good to know about and may come
in handy.

A good place to use `(</>)` is in your `listFilesInDir` function, e.g.:

```
listFilesInDir dir =
  getDirectoryContents >>= filterM (\x -> doesFileExist (dir </> x))
```

Now `dir` does not have to end in a `/` or `\\` because using `(</>)` will
add the appropriate separator.

**fileList**

Note that `fileList` is an IO-action, so in these lines:

```
fileSources <-fmap (map (source ++)) $ fileList
fileSinks <-fmap (map (sink ++)) $ fileList
```

you are repeating the IO-action twice. That is, you are performing
`getDirectoryContents` *twice* on the same directory. Instead you
want to perform `fileList`
only once and use its result to compute `fileSources` and `fileSinks`:

```
leafNames <- listFilesInDir source
let fileSources = map (source </>) leafNames
    fileSinks = map (sink </>) leafNames
zipWithM_ (writeFirstNLines n) fileSources fileSinks
```

Note I'm using `zipWithM_` here - it works just like `zipWithM` but discards
the results. It's more efficient because `zipWithM_` discards the result of
the zip operation immediately, whereas `zipWithM` saves the results in a
list thus consuming memory for data you'll never look at.

**hClose**

In Haskell you need to explicitly close your file handles when you are done
with them. Every process has limit on the number of handles which can be open at any one time, so if you never close any handles then eventually `openFile` will fail when you hit this limit.

A basic way to make sure your file handles always get closed is to use
the [`withFile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:withFile) function:

```
withFile :: FilePath -> IOMode -> (Handle -> IO r) -> IO r
```

`withFile` creates a file handle by opening a path with the specified IOMode
and passes the handle to an IO-action. It will ensure that the handle is
closed when the IO-action completes - whether it returns normally
or if an exception is thrown.

Using `withFile` your `writeFirstNLines` would look like:

```
writeFirstNLines n source sink = do
  withFile source ReadMode (\hin -> do
    withFile sink WriteMode (\hout -> do
      ... copy from hin to hout ...
    )
  )
```

Now both `hin` and `hout` will automatically get closed when the copy action
completes.

**replicateM**

Note that `replicateM_ n action` will always execute `action`
exactly `n` times - no more and no less. So this is not a good way
to write a loop which could be executed a variable number of times.

As an example of how inefficient using `replicateM_` here could be,
suppose that `n` is 1000 and you are operating on a 3 line file.
Then:

```
replicateM_ n readAndWrite
```

will execute `readAndWrite` 1000 times even though the last
997 calls won't copy any lines.

Here is a recipe for a loop which is executed at most `n` times
with the possibility of breaking out early:

```
loop n | n <= 0 = return ()
loop n = do quit <- condition       -- check condition
            if quit
              then return ()        -- break out early
              else ... do stuff...
                   loop (n-1)       -- perform next iteration
```

You can use this to copy the first n lines by substituting:

```
condition        =  hIsEOF hin
...do stuff...   =  hGetLine hin >>= hPutStrLn hout
```

Comment: You are the man. Let me work through this stuff. Thanks.